# Making certain li elements in a sortable list unsortable not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a list of images which is sortable to be able to chose the order of them. I never want the chose image item to be sortable, just the images themselves. This works fine most of the times, unless I start to remove and add images again. To reproduce the bug you can in the example:

1. Upload first image, the second image upload box should appear
2. Upload second image, the third image upload box should appear
3. Upload third image, the fourth image upload box should appear
4. Delete the first image by pressing the red X, the image should dissapear
5. Upload a third image again

After these steps the upload image box is now sortable, even if it has the non-sortable class attached to it. I.e. the box can be dragged around which should not be possible, and which is not possible from the beginning.

I tried to refresh the sortable list with this code but it had no effect:

```
$('#imageListItem_'+imageIndex).addClass('non-sortable-item');
$("#sortableList").sortable("option", "items", "li:not(.non-sortable-item)");
```

Here is a minimum reproducable example:

```js
// Init the page
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Make list of images sortable
    $( "#sortableList" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.non-sortable-item)"
    });
});

function uploadNewImage(thisObject, e){

    // Find image and see if it is of the correct type
    var imageFile = e.target.files[0];

    // Find this image number, hide upload option and display the image
    var imageNumber = thisObject.getAttribute("imageIndex");    
    var tempBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
    $('#enableFileUpload_'+imageNumber).css('display', 'none');
    $('#imageItem_'+imageNumber).css("background-image", "url('" + tempBlobURL + "')");
    $('#imageListItem_'+imageNumber).removeClass('non-sortable-item');
  $("#sortableList").sortable("option", "items", "li:not(.non-sortable-item)");


  // Show the delete and change image symbol
  $('#deleteUploadImageSymbol_'+imageNumber).css('display', 'block');

  // Show the next image element, if we have any more to show 
  $('*[id*=imageListItem_]:hidden').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
    return false;
  });

}

function deleteUploadedImage(imageIndex){

    var thisListItem = document.getElementById('imageListItem_'+imageIndex);

    // Find the image filename
    var img = document.getElementById('imageItem_'+imageIndex);
    var styles = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false);
    var imageURL = styles.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "");

    // Remove image and the buttons
    $('#imageItem_'+imageIndex).css('background-image', 'none');
    $('#deleteUploadImageSymbol_'+imageIndex).css('display', 'none');

    // Hide image wrapper and put it last in the list
    var imageWrapper = $('#imageListItem_'+imageIndex);
    imageWrapper.css('display', 'none');
    $('#sortableList').find('#imageListItem_'+imageIndex).appendTo('#sortableList');

    // Show image uploader
    $('#enableFileUpload_'+imageIndex).css('display', 'flex');

    // Make it not sortable
    $('#imageListItem_'+imageIndex).addClass('non-sortable-item');
    $("#sortableList").sortable("option", "items", "li:not(.non-sortable-item)");

}
```

```css
.sortable-list{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}
.upload-image-item{
    height: clamp(125px, 15vw, 200px);
    width: clamp(125px, 15vw, 200px);
    border: thin solid rgb(180 180 180);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(80 80 80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.delete-upload-image-symbol{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: rgb(190, 30, 30);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.upload-image-svg-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: clamp(125px, 15vw, 200px);
    font-size: 13px;    
}
.custom-file-upload{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.upload-image-svg{
    display: block;
    width: clamp(30px, 5vw, 42px);
    height: clamp(30px, 5vw, 42px);
    margin: auto;
}
.featured-upload-image-text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 100, 173, 0.9);
    border-radius: 0.4rem 0.4rem 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sortableList" class="sortable-list">        

  <li class="non-sortable-item" id="imageListItem_1">
    <div id="imageItem_1" class="upload-image-item">

      <span onclick="deleteUploadedImage(1);" style="display:none;" id="deleteUploadImageSymbol_1" class="delete-upload-image-symbol"> X</span>
      <span id="enableFileUpload_1" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
        <label for="imageUploadID_1" class="custom-file-upload">
          <div class="upload-image-svg">+</div>
          <div class="upload-image-text">Choose image</div>
        </label>
        <input onchange="uploadNewImage(this, event)" imageIndex="1" id="imageUploadID_1" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <img id="img-upload_1" style="display:none;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="non-sortable-item" id="imageListItem_2" style="display:none;">
    <div id="imageItem_2" class="upload-image-item">

      <span onclick="deleteUploadedImage(2);" style="display:none;" id="deleteUploadImageSymbol_2" class="delete-upload-image-symbol"> X</span>
      <span id="enableFileUpload_2" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
        <label for="imageUploadID_2" class="custom-file-upload">
          <div class="upload-image-svg">+</div>
          <div class="upload-image-text">Choose image</div>
        </label>
        <input onchange="uploadNewImage(this, event)" imageIndex="2" id="imageUploadID_2" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <img id="img-upload_2" style="display:none;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="non-sortable-item" id="imageListItem_3" style="display:none;">
    <div id="imageItem_3" class="upload-image-item">

      <span onclick="deleteUploadedImage(3);" style="display:none;" id="deleteUploadImageSymbol_3" class="delete-upload-image-symbol"> X</span>
      <span id="enableFileUpload_3" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
        <label for="imageUploadID_3" class="custom-file-upload">
          <div class="upload-image-svg">+</div>
          <div class="upload-image-text">Choose image</div>
        </label>
        <input onchange="uploadNewImage(this, event)" imageIndex="3" id="imageUploadID_3" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <img id="img-upload_3" style="display:none;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="non-sortable-item" id="imageListItem_4" style="display:none;">
    <div id="imageItem_4" class="upload-image-item">

      <span onclick="deleteUploadedImage(4);" style="display:none;" id="deleteUploadImageSymbol_4" class="delete-upload-image-symbol"> X</span>
      <span id="enableFileUpload_4" class="upload-image-svg-wrapper">
        <label for="imageUploadID_4" class="custom-file-upload">
          <div class="upload-image-svg">+</div>
          <div class="upload-image-text">Choose image</div>
        </label>
        <input onchange="uploadNewImage(this, event)" imageIndex="4" id="imageUploadID_4" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <img id="img-upload_4" style="display:none;">
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>


</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

**Why is the box not sortable from the beginning, but after it has had the class 'non-sortable-item' removed and then added again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to destroy the list and then re-initiate it again when adding or removing the class. So instead of:

```
$("#sortableList").sortable("option", "items", "li:not(.non-sortable-item)");
```

or

```
$("#sortableList").sortable("refresh");
```

I had to destroy and init again like this:

```
$("#sortableList").sortable("destroy");
$("#sortableList").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.non-sortable-item)"
});
```

It now works as expected, even if it feels like an ugly solution and that "refresh" should work.